# Firebase Authentication is not working for me

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In documentation for Auth with Facebook says:

> Make sure your OAuth redirect URI (e.g. my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler) is listed as one of your OAuth redirect URIs in your Facebook app's settings page on the Facebook for Developers site in the Product Settings > Facebook Login config..

But when I try it with my link - it not redirect at all (https://someproject-8fda3.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler). In console Auth with FB is switched on. But I still don't understand why it's not working (with google auth - same problem).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you have app and do want to use firebase functionality to authenticate the user with facebook you have to install FBSDK and implement it in your code.